# training with multiple csv files with keras

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I have a large dataset which is basically several csv files. What I am doing now is combining all together then creating one single csv / data frame. which is as follows :

```
path = './path'
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
list_ = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
    list_.append(df)

df_frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

Then it is becoming huge. Is there any other way of training a keras model with multiple data files?

Comment: You can customize your own generator to read data in batches, and apply `model.fit_generator()` to train.

Comment: There is an example on the TensorFlow website about how to consume multiple CSV files: https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_csv_data

Comment: @giser_yugang I have the similar problem but I have time series data, I can't mixup all in one dataframe. So I have 5 different dataframes ready can you please tell me how to train one Keras LSTM model for 5 different files. Thanks in advance

Comment: @SamudranilRoy You can refer [python - Reading multiple CSVs for Keras LSTM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54879511/python-reading-multiple-csvs-for-keras-lstm) and [Training Keras model with multiple CSV files](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/51249/training-keras-model-with-multiple-csv-files).